# Importing existing resources with multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We have four AWS accounts used to define different environments: dev, sqe, stg, prd. We're only now using CF and I'd like to import an existing resource into a stack.  As we roll this out each environment will get the new stack and I'm wondering if there's an easier way to import the resource in each env. than to initially go through the console to import the reasource while add the stack (would be nice if we could just deploy via our deployment system.)

What I was hoping for was something I could specify in the stack definition itself (e.g., "here's a bucket that already exists, take ownership"), but I'm not finding anything.  Currently it seems like the easiest route would be to create an empty stack in each environment which imports the resource and then just deploy as normal.

Also, what happens when/if an update fails and a stack gets stuck in ROLLBACK_COMPLETE? Do I have to go through this again after deleting the stack?

Comment: There is no capability that can import existing resources simply by pointing to the resources. Instead, the stack template needs to be updated and then an existing resource can be brought in 'as' that resource defined in the template.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described sounds exactly like your after a Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment (CICD) pipeline. Instead of trying to import existing resources into your accounts, your better off designing the cloudformation templates then deploying them to each environment through Code Pipeline. This will also provide a clean separation between the accounts instead of importing **stg** resources to **prd**.

A fantastic example and quickstart is the [serverless-cicd-for-enterprise](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/serverless-cicd-for-enterprise/) which should serve as a good starting point for you.

You can't get stuck on 'rollback complete', as that is the last action a failed change set executes. What it means is that it tried to update, couldn't and has reverted to the last successful deployment. If this is the first deployment (no successful deployments) you will need to delete the stack and try again. However, if you have had a successful deployment you can run an update stack.